# Framework-и для построения GUI

Tags: tkinter, javafx, pyqt, swing

Относительно недавно начал изучать Python и Java и естественно столкнулся с вопросом построения графических интерфейсов для десктопных приложений...

Задаюсь вопросом, стоит ли распыляться на множество целей и изучать "устаревшие" библиотеки (для Java это `Swing`, для Python `Tkinter`) в ущерб более "современным" (`PyQt` и `JavaFX` соотвественно). Или все таки разработчик должен так сказать разбираться во всем и иметь хотя бы базовое представление о каждой из них? Такая вот дилема. Понимаю, что сколько людей, столько и мнений, но хотелось бы услышать дельные советы по этому вопросу.

**UPD:**
Переформулирую вопрос, а точнее сформулирую его. Знаниями каких framework-ов обладаете вы? Как-то так...

Comment: Выбирайте на свой вкус, это не к нам вопрос. С каждым, из перечисленных вами инструментов, можно сделать многое + сами по-себе языки питон и джава имеют гораздо более широкое применение, чем просто интерфейсы для десктопа. Но конечно, стоит выбирать что-то более современное, хотя специалисты по Turbo Vision на паскале сейчас на вес золота, где-то, наверное. Главное найти где именно

Comment: Года два пишу десктопные приложения с библиотекой javafx, с нее сразу и начинал. С учетом дополнений типа controlsfx и собственных наработок, все что нужно для реализации интерфейса есть. Отмечу хорошую документацию и огромное количество действующих участников. Мне как новичку, именно в десктопном направлении, было просто и понятно. Есть ли смысл изучать swing? Наверное только для поддержки legacy продуктов (а их сейчас все еще много). Если Вы планируете именно свой проект (или с нуля), то в java однозначно лучше использовать javafx.

Answer (score 1):

И Tkinter и PyQt вполне активные библиотеки сегодня. И пишут на обеих. Другое дело, изучив PyQt вы потом достаточно просто сможете работать на всех тех языках, для которых есть соответствующие интерфейсы в Qt: C#, Java,  PHP, Ruby и далее по списку. С другой стороны лично мне Tkinter кажется более интуитивно-понятным.  Но ничего не мешает вам потратить несколько часов-дней, поставить оба интерфейса, немного с ним поиграться и принять самостоятельное решение, а не опираться на мнение неизвестных  вам людей с форума.